# Back full Label color in Finder

Tags: macos, finder

I would like the full label color back.
I hate the small dots, I can't understand why apply more than one color tag in the same file.
Where can I find the file that control this tags?
I don't want install other program to control it, like xtrafinder or similar.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you pls be more specific? Are you discussing the tags in the Finder app or somewhere else? Which macOS are you using?

Comment: These were called "labels" back in Mountain Lion days and were done away with when Mavericks hit the scene.  There's no setting that will re-enable it.  If this is something you want, you'll need a 3rd party solution.